# TextBox let '\n' be the carriage return

Tags: c++, winapi

TextBoxes created by "CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, "EDIT", "", ES_MULTILINE.."
require \r\n for a new line.
im redirecting my stdoutput into that textbox, which uses just '\n' to indicate a new line. and im not willing to replace all '\n' with '\r\n'
isn't there a way to let '\n' beeing a newline in textboxes?

thx

Comment: How exactly are you redirecting stdout to the text box? It seems like you must have some code to accomplish that, and it seems to perfect place to modify the line separators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure what you're asking is impossible (i.e. there's no magic setting to make Windows edit controls accept Unix-style newlines).

Comment: alright, thanks for letting me know.
so i really have to replace all the \n with \r\n :/

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what language you are using, but why not just do this (VB.NET Example):

```
TextBox1.Text=TextBox1.Text.Replace("\r\n","\n")
```

That should replace all the "\r\n" occurences with just "\n"

Answer (score 0):

\r\n is not a new line. It is a carriage return + new line. They are different things. It probably means more to people who work in the console world though because you can go to a new line without shifting back to character position 1.